# How to rewrite interface for ReactFC if array is returned?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, interface

Project style to use React.FC instead of direct types

This is work:

```
interface IConfigActions {
  iconColor: string;
}
```

```
const ConfigActions = ({iconColor}: IConfigActions) => {
  return (
    [
      { id: 1, icon: <MediaSVG style={{ fill: iconColor }} /> },
      { id: 2, icon: <GifSVG style={{ fill: iconColor }} /> },
      { id: 3, icon: <PollSVG style={{ fill: iconColor }} /> },
      { id: 4, icon: <EmojiSVG style={{ fill: iconColor }} /> },
      { id: 5, icon: <ScheduleSVG style={{ fill: iconColor }} /> },
    ]
  )
}
```

but the next code gives me an error

```
const ConfigActions:FC<IConfigActions> = ({iconColor}) => {
  return (
    [
      { id: 1, icon: <MediaSVG style={{ fill: iconColor }} /> },
      { id: 2, icon: <GifSVG style={{ fill: iconColor }} /> },
      { id: 3, icon: <PollSVG style={{ fill: iconColor }} /> },
      { id: 4, icon: <EmojiSVG style={{ fill: iconColor }} /> },
      { id: 5, icon: <ScheduleSVG style={{ fill: iconColor }} /> },
    ]
  )
}
```

> Type '({ iconColor }: IConfigActions) => { id: number; icon: Element; }[]' is not assignable to type 'FC<IConfigActions>'.
> Type '{ id: number; icon: Element; }[]' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, any>': type, props, keyts(2322)

Comment: In your code, you're trying to return an array of objects from the ConfigActions component. However, for a React functional component, you need to return a single React element (or a fragment of elements).

Comment: A component must return something that can be rendered, like JSX or a string. An array of objects can't be. What are you trying to do here exactly... ?

Comment: @super initially, only an array of elements was returned, but I needed to pass props (iconColor). In another component, a navigation bar was built based on this array.

Comment: Anything wrong with returning `<><MediaSVG ... /> <GifSVG ... /> ... </>`?

Comment: Also FYI. `IConfigActions` is the props passed in. What's returned is not in any way linked to the props passed in. You don't need to change it.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you're trying to return an array of objects from the ConfigActions component. However, for a React functional component, you need to return a single React element (or a fragment of elements).

You can wrap the above code as:

```
const ConfigActions: FC<IConfigActions> = ({ iconColor }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {[
        { id: 1, icon: <MediaSVG style={{ fill: iconColor }} /> },
        { id: 2, icon: <GifSVG style={{ fill: iconColor }} /> },
        { id: 3, icon: <PollSVG style={{ fill: iconColor }} /> },
        { id: 4, icon: <EmojiSVG style={{ fill: iconColor }} /> },
        { id: 5, icon: <ScheduleSVG style={{ fill: iconColor }} /> },
      ]}
    </div>
  );
};
```